# SQL Server mirroring causing issues

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

So we have a couple of SQL Server instances involved on mirroring without witness and operating mode is asynchronous in all cases.

After we set put mirroring in place, we started facing connections issue on our applications like this one:

> org.apache.torque.TorqueException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Could not retrieve connection info from pool
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user XXXXXX.

After some investigation we saw in the alert log of the mirrored instance errors like this:

> Login failed for user XXXXXX. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password.

Connection string used on the app side:

```
torque.dsfactory.service.connection.url = jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_IP:INSTANCE_PORT;databaseName=DB_NAME;applicationName=AP‌​P_NAME torque.dsfactory.service.connection.user = XXXXXX
```

So, this makes me think that somehow the application is trying to connect to the mirrored instance and since all logins are disabled there the connection is rejected.

Does anyone had this type of issues in the past? I do not see any problem on the mirroring configuration.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to send that valuable information.

Comment: torque.dsfactory.service.connection.url = jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_IP:INSTANCE_PORT;databaseName=DB_NAME;applicationName=APP_NAME
torque.dsfactory.service.connection.user = XXXXXX

Comment: This does not seems to be related to mirroring

Comment: Logins should not be DISABLED on a mirror server, that will cause your application to not properly work in the event of a fail over. I'd start by checking to see which server the connections are attempted from (which the IP will be part of the error text) and check for rogue processes. Running a packet capture from that server to verify may be needed. Overall, though, I wouldn't say this is a problem with mirroring but a problem with the server or the application configuration.

Comment: We don't want automatic fail over in place, so that's why the logins are disabled on the mirror side. I guess it may be related with mirroring because: 1) issue has started when we put mirroring in place. 2) on the app side we only have connection to the principal instance, so only the mirror can redirect the connection to the mirroring side...

Comment: Do you actually see any 18456's on the mirror server in the log?

Comment: Yes, I do see error 18456 on alert log of the mirror server.

Comment: Then chances are the configuration of the connection string is wrong. I do find it very interesting that you use the server ip over DNS and don't use the partner clause. Check the IP address for which server it is coming from on the mirror and run a netstat or network trace to figure out which process it is coming from.